# How to use a templated client display() function that takes a set as the parameter

Tags: c++, class, templates, set, codeblocks

I have to write a templated client function called DisplaySet() that gets as an argument a set, and displays the contents of the set. I am confused on how I can output the set, which is part of a class, in a client function. 
Here is my code:

"set.h"

```
template<class ItemType>
class Set
{
 public:
  Set();
  Set(const ItemType &an_item);
  int GetCurrentSize() const;
  bool IsEmpty() const;
  bool Add(const ItemType& new_entry);
  bool Remove(const ItemType& an_entry);
  void Clear();
  bool Contains(const ItemType& an_ntry) const; 
  vector<ItemType> ToVector() const;
  void TestSetImplementation() const;

 private:
  static const int kDefaultSetSize_ = 6;
  ItemType items_[kDefaultSetSize_]; 
  int item_count_;                    
  int max_items_;                 
  int GetIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;
};
template<class ItemType>
void DisplaySet(const Set<ItemType> &a_set);
```

"set.cpp"

```
template<class ItemType>
void DisplaySet(const Set<ItemType> &a_set){
    int a_size = a_set.GetCurrentSize(); //gets size of the set
    cout <<"Size display "<< a_size << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        cout << a_set[i] << endl; //i know this does not work because a_set is part of a class
    }
}
```

"main.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>   
#include "Set.h"   

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Set<int> b_set;

   b_set.Add(setArray[1]);
   b_set.Add(setArray[2]);
   b_set.Add(setArray[4]);
   b_set.Add(setArray[8]);
   DisplaySet(b_set);

   return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can explain how to use the function. Let me know if I need to post more of the code

Comment: I don't completely understand your question.  You pass a `Set` to DisplaySet, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Set` class does not have an overloaded `operator[]`, so calling `a_set[i]` is not going to work in your `DisplaySet` function.

Assuming that your `ToVector` function returns a vector of the items in the set, the DisplayFuntion can look like this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
//...
template<class ItemType>
void DisplaySet(const Set<ItemType> &a_set)
{
    std::vector<ItemType> v = a_set.ToVector();
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<ItemType>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Again, this is assuming that `ToVector` does as stated.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am getting for an answer 
0
2293436
1982137000
1981550990

Comment: Then your `Set` class is faulty.  The writing of the elements is not the issue.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how I can fix this, or what to look for?

Comment: You didn't post any code for `Set` except a class definition and your display function.  The bottom line is that it isn't the display function that is the problem, but no one knows what it is since we don't have all of your code.  But please open a separate question for these other issues.